# I can't display floating action menu on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I want to display floating action menu on recyclerview object.I have a lesson activity that display to saved lesson. I want to add floating action button its include 2 selection. When i added new dataif recylverview object is no have data my floating action menu is working good but when recyclerview is full its not working like the picture bottom of page. What can i do solved this problem ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu_fab_label=""
            app:menu_openDirection="up"
            app:menu_showShadow="true">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingAddButtonLesson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_label="Ders Ekle"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingAddButtonLesson2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_label="Toplam Kaç Soru Çözdüm"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />


        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvLesson"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place `FloatingActionMenu` below the `RecyclerView`, then `FloatingActionMenu` will show on top `RecyclerView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_login"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rvLesson"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu_fab_label=""
            app:menu_openDirection="up"
            app:menu_showShadow="true">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingAddButtonLesson"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_label="Ders Ekle"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingAddButtonLesson2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:fab_label="Toplam Kaç Soru Çözdüm"
                app:fab_size="mini"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />


        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```